# I want to upgrade by flutter version by I'm facing an error while updating dart sdk

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, bit

[image: i am getting this BITS error while updating by dart SDK]

Currently I'm using **Windows 10 OS** .
I wanna start flutter as web app but i got hanged here . Please help me out .

Comment: could you show your actual error? what I'm seeing on that screen is just getting starting with the download.

Comment: the downloading is not starting because of that BITS you  can see in blue color

Comment: have you tried using the actual terminal from Android Studio?

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.